# Why is BubbleUPnP not connecting to my minidlna server?

Tags: networking, android

I'm trying to stream video files from my Ubuntu computer to my Android tablet. My tablet is running BubbleUPnP, and I've just installed minidlna.

I can't seem to access video from BubbleUPnP. I've followed a few different setup guides on the web, and they all seem to be pretty easy. Follow a few configurations and start the service.

My [configuration file is here on Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7194198/).

The error I get on BubbleUPnP is "The remote server could not be joined due to timeout. Check that the server address is correct." I am certain I am using the right IP address, which is 192.168.0.2, and I've tried setting the port to 6544 wherever I could.

In `/etc/minidlna.conf` There are the following errors and one warning:

```
[2014/04/02 22:03:03] minidlna.c:898: warn: Starting MiniDLNA version 1.0.24 [SQLite 3.7.17].
[2014/04/02 22:03:03] minissdp.c:71: error: setsockopt(udp, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP): Address already in use
[2014/04/02 22:03:03] minissdp.c:121: warn: Failed to add multicast membership for address 192.168.0.2
[2014/04/02 22:03:03] minidlna.c:1006: warn: HTTP listening on port 6544
```

Can anyone suggest where I might be going wrong?

Comment: The close reason is wrong. MiniDLNA is available for all releases including 14.10. Only in 14.04. we have to install from a ppa until it's backported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to access your miniDLNA sever we need the following in addition

- Make sure the ports for traffic are open (firewall and router).
- We may want to open SSDP traffic on port 1900 UDP for multicast service announcement. In addition we may need to also open port 8200 TCP for trivnet1.
- If in the same network we may not need to define a `listening_ip`.

**Note for 14.04:** MiniDLNA was removed upstream from the repositories but is available through the [backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) repository.

Comment: Hope it works (I haven't upgraded my miniDLNA serving system yet)!

Comment: Reinstalled miniDLNA and it just seemed to automagically work this time.

Answer (score 0):

But don't upgrade to 14.04 yet if you need minidlna. It's been deleted from that version of Ubuntu. If you do upgrade, you'll have to compile and install minidlne yourself. Follow the instructions at http://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-minidlna-on-ubuntu-ultimate-guide/
 but also make sure to install "gettext" prior to building minidlna.